# 403 error on submit at the plugin options page

Tags: options

On my plugin options page, There is an option for saving an ad code

but adding specific content containing `"<script"` tag on any of the fields(textarea) made the server generate a 403 error and refuse processing the request

here is the textarea html

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="ad1"><?php echo stripslashes(  get_option('ad1') )?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by adding the word "content" to the field name

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="ad1_content"><?php echo stripslashes(  get_option('ad1_content') )?></textarea>
```

It then worked just fine

I think this is a security issue that accepted the script tag for fields containing content (used by wordpress in editor by the way) in name and rejecting the others.